# Have .bat file continue after it runs a command

Tags: batch-file

I need to figure out this seemingly *very simple* issue on windows .bat file. I have been using Linux for past 10 years full-time, so I am in pretty unfamiliar territory when it comes to .bat scripts.

We have some units tests that need to run on from this .bat file, and a build needs to be generated after the tests have run.

The bat file itself is very simple, I was thinking of just chaining the commands:

```
cls
echo "Running test suite - CRMSync"
echo 
echo 
REM from command: --static-backup
phpunit --bootstrap test/bootstrap_test.php --verbose --log-junit              
echo "Running  phploc for CRMSync"
phploc --count-tests --verbose > C:\CRMsync\testResults\phploc\index.html
echo "Executing phing"
phing
```

Now, simple enough except nothing is executed past phpunit command. How do I deal with this?
The unit tests run fine, but I am suspecting it could even be in the unit test lib that process is killed. Is there a way to fork the process somehow or get the other commands below to run?

Thanks SO'ers, as always, any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: you're searching in the wrong direction: if phpunit crashes the batch will continue

Comment: do phploc and phing execute if you comment out phpunit call?

Comment: This is more of a [su] thing...

Comment: You should try to understand why it crashes instead of changing call. Dirty fixes always bite you (or your successor) later.

Comment: @CharlesB Hey bud you were right, the phploc script was choking without outputing anything and I thought it was running fine. What is wrong with using call though, if you need a script to keep going regardless of failures? Is there a way to cactch return status of the script? I will peek into this tomorrow out of curiosity, I will maybe not touch windows again for a long while once this is up and working.  Thanks for your input, +1'ed your comments for taking the time to clue me in! ;)

Comment: Glad it helped; don't forget to post it as answer though :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Similar to the post ujifgc, I use "start /b ..." in these situations.  If you encapsulate the call to phpunit in another batch file, you can use "call".

Comment: This does not wait the command to be completed before passing to the next line

Answer (score 23):

I had the same problem for a development script that I made. And I tried all given solutions without being successful. At the end, I did it with **cmd /C**.

From the windows docs it will:

> Run Command and then terminate

So for example, you can use it as follows:

```
cls
echo "Running test suite - CRMSync"
echo 
echo 
REM from command: --static-backup
cmd /C phpunit --bootstrap test/bootstrap_test.php --verbose --log-junit              
echo "Running  phploc for CRMSync"
cmd /C phploc --count-tests --verbose > C:\CRMsync\testResults\phploc\index.html
echo "Executing phing"
cmd /C phing
```

I hope you find this useful.

Comment: This is the correct way to do it in my experience: it waits for the command to be completed before passing to the next line

Comment: This helped, just a small note, I would to use `%comspec% /C` instead of `cmd /C`.

Answer (score 8):

Is phpunit itself a batch file (I don't do much PHP, so am not familiar with the tool)? If so, try using:

```
call phpunit --bootstrap test/bootstrap_test.php --verbose --log-junit
```

Comment: I had the same problem with a .bat file. At first it calls 'composer update', than runs '7zip.exe -a ...'. The second command wasn't executed. I tried 'call composer update', and now it runs in the proper way. My 'composer' command is a .bat file too. It consists: "php "%~dp0composer.phar" %*"

Answer (score 2):

Try `start /WAIT phpunit ...` to fork process and wait for it or just `start phpunit ...` to fork and continue. Help is here: `start /?`

Comment: Yeah! Thanks. Will look into this first thing tomorrow mate.

Answer (score 2):

I used

> start /b code .
>
> cmd /k ng serve --build-optimizer --aot

to start Visual Studio Code and then a node js server.

But the Command line glitched with the % update text and more.

I then used

> cmd /C code .
>
> cmd /k ng serve --build-optimizer --aot

and the glitching stopped for the server progress update.